# How to send headers from controller into another class in Java

Tags: java, spring

I have a controller like below

*SubmitBatchController.java*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/"})
@Api(value = "batch", tags = {"Batch "}, authorizations = {@Authorization(value="JwtToken")})
public class SubmitBatchController extends BasicController {

@PostMapping(value = "v1/batch", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public CommonResponse<BatchSubmissionResponseModel> submitBatchClaim(
@ApiParam(hidden = true) @RequestHeader(required = false) String transId,
@ApiParam(hidden = true) @RequestHeader(required = false) String paymentReleaseInd,
@ApiParam(hidden = true) @RequestHeader(required = false) String emailMatchedInd,
@ApiParam(hidden = true) @RequestHeader(vrequired = false) String role,
@RequestBody BatchSubmissionRequestModel batchSubmissionRequestModel,
BindingResult br, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

LocalDateTime startLocaleDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
BatchSubmissionResponseModel batchSubmissionResponseModel = new BatchSubmissionResponseModel();
ContextBase ctxBase = getChainBaseContext(request);
ctxBase.put(PARAM_LOC.RESPONSE, batchSubmissionResponseModel);
HeaderRequestModel headers = new headerRequestModel();  
batchSubmissionRequestModel.setTransId(transId);    
headers.setRole(role);
headers.setPaymentReleaseInd(paymentReleaseInd);
headers.setEmailMatchedInd(emailMatchedInd);

batchSubmissionRequestModel.setHeaderRequestModel(headers);
}
}
```

*BatchSubmissionRequestModel.java*

```
public class BatchSubmissionRequestModel {

@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true) // this is captured as a header and set in the controller
@NotBlank(message = "Headers.transId.NotBlank")
private String transId;
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
private HeaderRequestModel headerRequestModel;

public String getTransId() {
return transId;
}
public void setTransId(String transId) {
this.transId = transId;
}
public HeaderRequestModel getHeaderRequestModel() {
return headerRequestModel;
}
public void setHeaderRequestModel(HeaderRequestModel headerRequestModel) {
this.headerRequestModel= headerRequestModel;
}
}
```

*HeaderRequestModel.java*

```
public class HeaderRequestModel {     
    private String paymentReleaseInd;
    private String emailMatchedInd;
    private String role;
    public String getPaymentReleaseInd() {
        return paymentReleaseInd;
    }
    public void setPaymentReleaseInd(String paymentReleaseInd) {
        this.paymentReleaseInd = paymentReleaseInd;
    }
    public String getEmailMatchedInd() {
        return emailMatchedInd;
    }
    public void setEmailMatchedInd(String emailMatchedInd) {
        this.emailMatchedInd = emailMatchedInd;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Now I have another class, which has to take the headers from `SubmitBatchController.java` & set it into `FullEligibilityService.java`

*FullEligibilityRequestModel.java*

```
public class FullEligibilityRequestModel{
private String transId;
private HeaderRequestModel headerRequestModel;

public String getTransId() {
return transId;
}
public void setTransId(String transId) {
this.transId = transId;
}

public DapHeaderRequestModel getDapHeaderRequestModel() {
return dapHeaderRequestModel;
}
public void setDapHeaderRequestModel(DapHeaderRequestModel dapHeaderRequestModel) {
this.dapHeaderRequestModel = dapHeaderRequestModel;
}
}
```

*FullEligibilityService.java*

> (request is mapped to FullEligibilityRequestModel)

```
@Service
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class FullEligibilityServiceextends extends AServiceTask <FullEligibilityRequestModel, FullEligibilityResponseModel>{

private static final String HEADER_FULL_ELIGIBILITY_TRANS_ID = "transId";
private static final String HEADER_PAYMENT_RELEASE_INDICAATOR =  "paymentReleaseInd"; 
private static final String HEADER_EMAIL_MATCHED_INDICATOR = "emailMatchedInd";
private static final String HEADER_ROLE = "role";

@Override
protected void processTask() {
try {

Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
headers.put(HEADER_FULL_ELIGIBILITY_TRANS_ID, request.getTransId());
headers.put(HEADER_PAYMENT_RELEASE_INDICAATOR, request.getHeaderRequestModel().getPaymentReleaseInd()); // getting NULL
headers.put(HEADER_EMAIL_MATCHED_INDICATOR, request.getHeaderRequestModel().getEmailMatchedInd()); // getting NULL
headers.put(HEADER_DAP_ROLE, request.getHeaderRequestModel().getRole()); // getting NULL
.....
}
catch (Exception e) {
LOGGER.error("FullEligibilityService.processTask call failed");
exception = e;
status = STATUS_TASK_EXCEPTION;
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I'm not able to get the headers set in `SubmitBatchController.java` into `FullEligibilityService.java`, due to which I get null values.

Can someone help me how to set the `PaymentReleaseInd, EmailMatchedInd, HeaderRequestModel` set in `SubmitBatchController.java` into  `FullEligibilityService.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject an instance of `FullEligibilityService` into `SubmitBatchController` as follows and then you just need to call the corresponding method with the required parameters:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/"})
@Api(value = "batch", tags = {"Batch "}, authorizations = {@Authorization(value="JwtToken")})
public class SubmitBatchController extends BasicController {

    @Autowired
    FullEligibilityService fullEligibilityService;

    @PostMapping(value = "v1/batch", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public CommonResponse<BatchSubmissionResponseModel> submitBatchClaim(
      @ApiParam(hidden = true) @RequestHeader(required = false) String transId,
      @ApiParam(hidden = true) @RequestHeader(required = false) String paymentReleaseInd,
      @ApiParam(hidden = true) @RequestHeader(required = false) String emailMatchedInd,
      @ApiParam(hidden = true) @RequestHeader(vrequired = false) String role,
      @RequestBody BatchSubmissionRequestModel batchSubmissionRequestModel,
      BindingResult br, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

          LocalDateTime startLocaleDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
          BatchSubmissionResponseModel batchSubmissionResponseModel = new BatchSubmissionResponseModel();
          ContextBase ctxBase = getChainBaseContext(request);
          ctxBase.put(PARAM_LOC.RESPONSE, batchSubmissionResponseModel);
          HeaderRequestModel headers = new headerRequestModel();  
          batchSubmissionRequestModel.setTransId(transId);    
          headers.setRole(role);
          headers.setPaymentReleaseInd(paymentReleaseInd);
          headers.setEmailMatchedInd(emailMatchedInd);

          fullEligibilityService.processTask(paymentReleaseInd, emailMatchedInd, headers);
    }

   (...)
}
```

You need to change Service to accept the data you need as follows:

```java
@Service
public class FullEligibilityServiceextends extends AServiceTask <FullEligibilityRequestModel, FullEligibilityResponseModel>{

public void processTask(String paymentReleaseInd, String emailMatchedInd, HeaderRequestModel headers) {
    (...) //Whatever logic you want to implement
}
```

Right now you are trying to pass around the data you need via request headers which is definitely a bad practice.

Comment: I'm new to Java, still learning, can you let me know how to call the corresponding method ? I mean which method and where to call to get the value Eg: ```PaymentReleaseInd``` from ```SubmitBatchController```  to ```FullEligibilityService```

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check it ;)

Comment: ```processTask()``` cannot be overridden 

```processTask(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) has protected access in com.batch.services.eligibilityws.FullEligibilityService FullEligibilityService.java:[84,9] ```


and


```method does not override or implement a method from a supertype. ```

Any solution ?

Comment: Yes, you need to change it in `AServiceTask` to be defined as follows: `public void processTask(String paymentReleaseInd, String emailMatchedInd, HeaderRequestModel headers);`.